# Python Regex matching with or without

Tags: python, regex

This is my expression:

```
r'.*?(\d*)\s(good|bad).*\:\s(\d*)'`
```

The strings:

```
Hello 30 good. found: 50.

Hello 10 bad.
```

My question is: My expression matches (30, good and 50) for the first string, but how do I get it to match (10, bad) for the second one?

As of now, the expression is omitting the second line since it does not fit the description

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just make the second part optional by using `?` quantifier: -

```
r'.*?(\d*)\s(good|bad)(?:.*\:\s(\d*))?'
```

Using `(?:.*\:\s(\d*))?` makes the pattern `.*\:\s(\d*)` optional. As `?` means match `0 or 1`.

Note that, I have used a `non-capturing` group, for that extra grouping to make it optional. By using this, your capturing groups numbering would not be altered from what the current one is. Because, a *non-capturing group* - the `(?:...)` thing, is not considered in the captured group count.

Comment: @mgilson.. Yeah, I've explained accordingly.

Comment: So you have.  +1 for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
r'.*?(\d+)\s(good|bad)[^\d]*(\d*)'
```